# Is it always safe to change the NR_syscalls value?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls

I need to modify the maximum number of system-calls belonging to the syscalls-table in order to insert 4 new system-calls in kernel 2.6.32. On the other hand I know some static structures in the image of the kernel have fixed linear address within the kernel. So, my question is: could this lead to corrupt the memory layout of the image initially loaded in memory?

Comment: I doesn't know about `static structures in the image of the kernel have fixed linear address within the kernel` which restricts number of system calls. But you can just add new ones and try to compile. If it would lead to incorrect kernel image, you will get error at compile or link stage.

Comment: Think about to the swapper_pg_dir pointer. It's value is known at the compilation time. Assume now I expand the system-calls table, therefore every other subsequent structure should shift ahead in memory. However PGD address is fixed and alloc_bootmem_lowpages could start reading data in a bad address. Obviously empirical results will make me conscious of "work" or "does not eork", but surely will not answer "why" in both cases.

Comment: It is linker who checks that any fixed-address section doesn't interleave with other sections. I see no needs to recheck this manually. Yes, there are cases when exceeded object size may decrease perfomance(because of cache issues), but these cases are usually explicitely described in the source code, or even checked(using `BUILD_BUG_ON` macro and similar).